# Optimal NGINX config for Nuxt 3 PM2

Tags: nginx, ssl, pm2, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

My NGINX config for Nuxt 3 hosted with PM2 on Ubuntu finally works fine. I just don't fully understand each block and why I need my redirects and alias.

So my questions are:

1. Is this really the ideal NGINX config or do I need to do these weeks only because I might haven't set up my Nuxt 3 in an ideal way?
2. Why do I need?: alias /var/www/example.com/reponame/.output/public/_nuxt;
3. Why do I need?: rewrite  ^/_nuxt(/.*) $1 break;

```
server {
server_name www.example.com;

# ssl_* directives here
# www to non-www for SEO canonical reasons
return 301 http://example.com$request_uri;

    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
server_name example.com;
# ssl_* directives here

#### FOR PM2 ####
location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3003;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
        
root /var/www/example.com/reponame;
index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

location = /favicon.ico {
log_not_found off; access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
}

location /_nuxt/ {
alias /var/www/example.com/reponame/.output/public/_nuxt;
### any difference to use this directory? alias /var/www/example.com/reponame/.nuxt/dist/client/;
}

location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpeg|jpg|png|woff|ttf|otf|svg|woff2|webp)$ 
{
rewrite ^/_nuxt(/.*) $1 break;
}

listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
server_name test.example.com;
# ssl_* directives here
root /var/www/example.com/test;
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

} 

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

listen 80;
server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = test.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
listen 80;
server_name test.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```